# Using spark dataFrame to load data from HDFS

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Can we use DataFrame while reading data from HDFS.
I have a tab separated data in HDFS.

I googled, but saw it can be used with NoSQL data

Answer (score 9, accepted):

DataFrame is certainly not limited to NoSQL data sources. Parquet, ORC and JSON support is natively provided in 1.4 to 1.6.1; text delimited files are supported using the spark-cvs package.

If you have your tsv file in HDFS at /demo/data then the following code will read the file into a DataFrame

```
sqlContext.read.
  format("com.databricks.spark.csv").
  option("delimiter","\t").
  option("header","true").
  load("hdfs:///demo/data/tsvtest.tsv").show
```

To run the code from spark-shell use the following:

```
--packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.4.0
```

In Spark 2.0 csv is natively supported so you should be able to do something like this:

```
spark.read.
  option("delimiter","\t").
  option("header","true").
  csv("hdfs:///demo/data/tsvtest.tsv").show
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding correctly, you essentially want to read data from the HDFS and you want this data to be automatically converted to a DataFrame.

If that is the case, I would recommend you [this](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) spark csv library. Check this out, it has a very good documentation.