# How to load data from HDFS using SparkR?

Tags: hdfs, sparkr

I am new to Hadoop and Spark. I am using Spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7. Using SparkR I want to load (read) data from Hadoop 2.7.3 HDFS.

I know, I can point to my Hadoop file using "hdfs://somepath-to-my-file" but I could not find a function in SparkR to do the job. read.df() doesn't work.

I am using sparkR.session() to connect to my Spark session.
For launching R interface for Spark, I ran sparkR from spark's bin location.

In short, I want to load csv file from HDFS using sparkR.

Please help. If possible, provide example.

Thanks,
SG

Answer (score 0):

[Using spark dataFrame to load data from HDFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37638618/using-spark-dataframe-to-load-data-from-hdfs)

For converting Data frame to RDD:

```
converted.rdd <- SparkR:::toRDD(dataframe)
```

Comment: Hi Arun, thanks for the reply. May be I am wrong, but I couldn't find toRDD() function. I also visited the link provided by you, I was not able to execute those commands successfully from the link. I also edited my question tiny bit so that I can make myself clear about what I am looking for.

Comment: I have answered in this link -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44463640/reading-csv-data-into-sparkr-after-writing-it-out-from-a-dataframe/44523247#44523247

Comment: Hi Arun, I saw another link provided by you. Since I am using Spark 2.1.1, it does not seems to have sqlContext. I tried exact steps from your link, except that I have Spark 2.1.1. May be I am missing something. Thanks.

Comment: read.df since 1.4.0 & loadDF since 1.6.0. kindly post what error you are getting..

Comment: Hi @Arun, sorry for the delay. Because of some issues I had to switch to Spark 2.2.0. Here is the error that I see when using read.df()/loadDF(). I could not grab the full screen, 
-------
imes; aborting job
17/08/11 10:17:02 ERROR r.RBackendHandler: loadDF on org.apache.spark.sql.api.r.
SQLUtils failed
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)

Comment: Dont know how to format here. I used <br/> for line break. In pyspark or scala reading from hdfs works. See below (for scala example):  <br/>
scala> val myFile="hdfs://localhost:9000/mydata/train.csv"  <br/>
myFile: String = hdfs://localhost:9000/mydata/train.csv  <br/>

scala> val txtfile = sc.textFile(myFile)  <br/>
txtfile: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = hdfs://localhost:9000/mydata/train.csv MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at <console>:26  <br/>

scala> txtfile.count()  <br/>
res0: Long = 892  <br/>

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find solution to the error, kindly share the code you have give to execute(give fully how you launched the sparkR & read the csv file)

A work around solution would be.

```
Option A:
# reading the file stored in local not in HDFS but in R
R_dataframe <- read.csv(file="mydata/train.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
#Note(If the file is too big it cant hold as it depends on RAM size, 
so u can increase the driver memory while starting sparkR 
by ".bin/sparkR --driver-memory 12g")

#convert R dataframe to sparkR dataframe:
sparkR_dataframe <- as.DataFrame(R_dataframe)

Option B:
Read it in Python as RDD from HDFS and save as parquet file.
#convert RDD to dataframe
df = rdd.toDF()
#save df as parquet file.
df.write.parquet("train.parquet")
#In sparkR session read the file:
train_df <- read.parquet("train.parquet")
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to mention "source" parameter in read.df() and loadDF(). Here are my steps:

```
#step1: launch hadoop standalone (using start-dfs.cmd and start-yarn.cmd)
#step2: launch spark standalone just by typing sparkR
#step3: run following command to load a csv file from HDFS
myfile <- read.df(path="hdfs://localhost:9000/mydata/train.csv", source="csv")

#step4: print few lines from myfile
head(myfile)
```

Note that in my code above my train.csv file resides in mydata directory in HDFS. 
Functions read.df() and loadDF() worked equally.
This whole setup was in Windows8.1 with following:

1. Hadoop 2.7.3 (standalone)
2. Spark 2.2.0 (standalone)
3. R 3.3.3 x64
4. Java version 1.8.0_144

Thanks.

Comment: #step2: launch spark standalone just by typing sparkR - `sparkR --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.0.3` #step3: run following command to load a csv file from HDFS - `myfile <- read.df(sqlContext, "hdfs://localhost:9000/mydata/train.csv", "com.databricks.spark.csv", header="true")` Have you tried this